# array.contains firebase reference object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why `array.conatins()` return false when object which I checked is in my array.. This is array of references from firebase.

```
    if(props.event){
        const userRef = firebase.firestore().collection('uzytkownik').doc(currentUser);
        console.log(props.event.uczestnicy.includes(userRef))
        console.log("userRef", userRef)
        console.log("uczestnicy[2]", props.event.uczestnicy[2])
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use normal JavaScript equality to compare if two [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) objects are not "equal" to each other.  What you could do instead is use the [isEqual()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#isequal) method to compare two references.  (JavaScript arrays don't know to use this method to check for equality.)